# grep and re-direct to csv

Tags: shell-script, grep, csv, text-formatting

This is the campaign log that I am parsing. Based on call-id I do grep.

Orginal Progress-log as follows:

```
FilePlayer::run:: Finished audio file is /voip/VoiceCampaigSetup/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/waves.war/waveFiles/AA/E1/welcome1.g711u for 1598852543429-8681@81.171.12.213
FilePlayer::run:: going to play next audio file /voip/VoiceCampaigSetup/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/waves.war/waveFiles/AA/E1/Announcementbui.g711u for 1598852543429-8681@81.171.12.213
```

The above is for 1 user and similarly for 5 users as discussed earlier post.
In the script, I took a number of users from the DB and corresponding call-id and iterating for 5 times, and the grep used in the script are:

```
START="FilePlayer::run:: Finished audio file is /voip/VoiceCampaigSetup/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/waves.war/waveFiles/AA/guest/"
END=" for $call_id"
grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log>>$CURRENTPATH/op2.csv
```

Iam getting output as welcome1.g711u, Announcement1.g711u per call-id and so on.

But I want the output as

```
welcome1.g711u, Announcement1.g711u (for call-id1)
welcome1.g711u, Announcement1.g711u (for call-id2)..
```

till 5 such call-ids. Still I can transpose immediately after first call-id1 parse like

```
sed 'N;s/\n\(Announcement\)/ \1/;P;D' $CURRENTPATH/E32.csv >$CURRENTPATH/E36.csv.
```

Problem, is if only Announcement alone played and not the welcome... this is not the right way.

To be more perfect way of parsing is:

```
9841778579,welcome1,Announcement1
9841778580,welcom1,Announcement1
```

Comment: I have formatted your question for clarity. But your example log entries and expected output snippets do not match (as far as I can tell). Please use a more appropriate sample of data.

Comment: Hi, Haxel, I have value in shell variable $target_users (populated from db) and grep command to parse the welcome & Announcement that was played [say]welcome.g711u, Announcement.g711u and is redirected to E40.csv. But I want, the user stored in the shell variable to be printed in the 1st column of the E40.csv and welcome.g711u in the 2nd column and Announcement.g711u in the 3rd column of a row. In short, the 1st row of the E40.csv should be as follows:9841778679,welcome.g711u,Announcement.g711u and I will iterate the same through loops for the rest of the users from the log.

Comment: grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log | sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'>>$CURRENTPATH/E40.csv
writing the users in the another csv file and joining it is not the right idea.

Comment: I want to redirect the user name stored in the shell variable into the 1st column of the CSV file and strings searched to grep should also be redirected to the 2nd and 3rd column of the same CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have asked a previous question about converting the output of `grep` to a comma-separated list. There, the suggested solution was in the form of `grep ... | paste -d ',' - -`. You can extend the same approach for this case as well. Just print the value of the call-id variable, and pass it to the `paste` command.

```
{ printf "%s\n" "$call-id"; grep .... ; } | paste -d ',' - - -
```

Which will give you the required output format:

```
123456789,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
```

Comment: Haxiel, I used to grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log | sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'>>$CURRENTPATH/E40.csv to get the output welcome1,Announcement1 in the .csv file. call_id is populated from db. However, the user id is in in the variable $target_users. Your are suggesting to do like { printf "%s\n" "$target_users"; grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)"  $IVRLOG$Progress_log | sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'} | paste -d ','....

Comment: Assuming that the 'target_users' variable contains just one ID, yes.You don't need `sed` here; `paste` will do the conversion from '\n' to ','.

Comment: Haxiel, user id is many and I am looping over it and re-direct to .csv file

Comment: Haxiel, thanks for your help. I solved the scenario with your suggestion as follows: if grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log; then
echo "Match found"
{ printf "%s," "$target_users"; grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log | sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'; }>>$CURRENTPATH/E41.csv
else
echo "Match not found"
{ printf "%s\n" "$target_users"; }>>$CURRENTPATH/E41.csv
fi
done

Comment: That's good. A suggestion regarding this bit of code: you're running `grep` twice - once in the `if` condition, and once inside the body. It would be better to run it once, capture the output in a variable, and then use the variable to test the condition and print the output. If the log file is large, you should also see a performance boost with this change.

Comment: Yes, I change the code accordingly, Haxiel.